# Concept: The graph component

Tags: graph-theory, definition, graph-isomorphism

I have the following definition for a `Component` of a graph:

> A subgraph $H$ of a graph $G$ is a component of $G$ if $H$ is a maximal connected subgraph of $G$, that is, there is no larger connected subgraph of $G$ having $H$ as a subgraph.

---

Can someone give me some examples of this? I am having trouble understanding what this would be. Could I take for example $K_4$ and remove one of the vertices and have **one** component of four, or would there only be one component since removing any vertex the graph is isomorphic to removing any of the other three?

Thank you.

Comment: @Casteels I think graph isomorphism is a related tag if you see my question body(I don't mean to be rude, see [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naleynXS7yo).) Are tags that are only part of the sub-question not acceptable?

Comment: @Casteels does $K_4$ have four components or one? I think that would likely clear up my understanding problems

Comment: It has one component. In general, take a vertex $w$ in the graph, and then let $W$ be all vertices you can reach from $w$ by some path. Then one component of $G$ will be the subgraph $H=(W,E|_W)$, where $E|_W$ is the set of all edges joining two vertices in $W$. But there may be other vertices in $G$ that weren't reachable from $w$, and so you can take one of these and get a second component.

Comment: @Casteels Thank you, I think I understand now. Could you please review my attempt answer below?

Comment: @Casteels I did fix that below attempt, and I am pretty much certain it is correct. If that upvote was yours, I will take that to mean it is correct now :)

Comment: Yes it was my upvote. By the way, for future reference, since when you "cut out"/deleted vertex $3$, you got an increased number of compnents, the vertex $3$ is called a *cut vertex*.

Comment: @Casteels Oh, very nice. Thank you for that! (I see that there cutting an edge with increased components is a bridge as well). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Note: I am the asker of this question. This is my attempt.

A component of a graph is a joint region, meaning: If a graph is not connected, each connected area is a component. So $K_4$ has $1$ component, which is itself and the following graph has $1$ component:

[image: Graph with two 3-cycles connected together by one vertex. E.g. Two triangles touching at a point.]

But if $V_3$ is removed, we have two components, both connected regions:

[image: Four vertices that have only two edges where there are two pairs. E.g. a pairing of two couples]

Answer (score 0):

The *components of a graph* are often referred to in the literature as the *connected components of a graph*. It is intuitively clear what they are.